# Como mostrar página de facebook en el contenido principal de mi aplicación?

Tags: android, fragment

Con Android Studio.
Ayuda por favor estoy queriendo mostrar una página en el contenido principal de mi aplicación en el cual estoy usando un Navigation Drawer, por lo que en este caso se usan Fragments, quiero decir que anteriormente necesitaba que esto se mostrará con la app de facebook, pero lo que ahora quiero es que no se salga de mi aplicación, he usado el siguiente código pero abre la página en el navegador:

```
    String url="https://www.facebook.com/uniagustiniana?ref=hl/";
    WebView view=(WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.wvfacebook);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
```

Además tambien usé antes el siguiente código, pero como decía, de esta manera abre la app de facebook:

```
    String facebookId = "fb://page/142009805915476";
    String urlPage = "http://www.facebook.com/uniagustiniana?ref=hl/";
    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(facebookId )));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Log.e(TAG, "Aplicación no instalada.");
        //Abre url de pagina.
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlPage)));
    }
```

Quisiera que la página de facebook se muestre como en la imagen de ilustración, que continue presente la barra de herramientas o toolbar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con cambiar la parte de tu URL en vez de poner "www" usa "m", tu url seria algo así : "https://m.facebook.com/uniagustiniana?ref=hl/", a mi me resulto, espero te sirva.